# Using INDEX Mysql in Active Tables

Tags: mysql

I would like to know about using Mysql INDEX in active table. So far I could learn

1. Index could be helpful to escalate the process quicker, especially if each row is totally different
2. Index could be useful while selecting or sorting a big table data
3. Index can slow while INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE

So, I have question, how if we put INDEX in an active transaction tables. I mean the table always updated, inserted and deleted. However, we need to achieve fast process while doing SELECT. Is Using INDEX proper? Or should we avoid using INDEX?

I just thought that we can use INDEX while we often use SELECT. However, I still have some doubts. Hopefully, you can explain regarding this problem.

I would like to know more about mysql INDEX since I have read many sources but do not get complete information. Hopefully, someone could explain it briefly

Comment: This will be a good resource for you.  https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Summary answer to 1. 2. 3.  Yes, Yes, Yes, the benefits of having appropriate indexing make number 3. NOT an issue.  The slow down is nothing compared to the speed improvements of 1. and 2. Learn how to use EXPLAIN SELECT to determine where you need indexes.  Tip, search for  MySQL EXPLAIN tutorial for helpful guidance.

Comment: Sure, I am still reading from the reference you've given. Its really useful and easy to understand

Comment: Great, Happy to share this with you.  View profile for contact info, please.